# Variable doesn't change inside for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying to create a function that checks if one of the keys (name1, name2) exists, then assign the value of it to a variable.

If it does exist and it's name1, then assign "left" to the variable `section`. If it's name2, then assign "right" to the variable `section`.

But right now, I only see `value` being updated, but `section` stays put at "left", even if only name2 is in `obj`.

```
const obj = {name1: "John", name2: "Jane"};

for (var key of Object.keys(obj)) {
  let value = '';
  let section = '';

  if (name1) {
   value = (Object.entries(obj)[0][1]);
   section = "left";
  } else if (name2) {
   value = (Object.entries(obj)[0][1]);
   section = "right";
  }

  value = Object.assign({}, {value, section});

  console.log(value);
}
```

Comment: `if (name1)` ? Did you mean `if (key === 'name1')`? Same for `name2`

Comment: Neither name1 or name2 are even defined anywhere.

Comment: Why do yuo need a loop for this? Just use `if (obj.hasOwnProperty('name1'))`

Comment: your code actually results in `"ReferenceError: name1 is not defined"` - unless `name1` is declared somewhere

Comment: The code you posted can't be producing the result you claim, unless you've set `name1` and `name2` earlier. Please post a [mcve] that actually demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your variables name1 and name2 are not defined in your loop.

You should replace them with a test on a strings.

```
const obj = {name1: "John", name2: "Jane"};

for (var key of Object.keys(obj)) {
  let value = '';
  let section = '';

  if (key == "name1") {
   value = (Object.entries(obj)[0][1]); // element 0 of Object.entries(obj), "John"
   section = "left";
  } else if (key == "name2") {
   value = (Object.entries(obj)[1][1]); // element 1 of Object.entries(obj), "Jane"
   section = "right";
  }

  value = Object.assign({}, {value, section});

  console.log(value);
}
```

But you code is too complicated, you can replace it with a simplier version:

```
const obj = {name1: "John", name2: "Jane"};

for (var key in obj) {

  if (key === "name1") {
   obj['section'] = 'left';
   break;
  } else if (key === "name2") {
   obj['section'] = 'right';
   break;
  }
}

//move the console log outside the loop
console.log(obj);
```

Edit: I forgot to break the loop

Answer (score 0):

The values in the loop aren't changing because you're saving the 1st element of the 0th element of the output of Object.entries(obj). This means you always get "John", whether section is "left" or "right".

```
const obj = {name1: "John", name2: "Jane"};

for (var key of Object.keys(obj)) {
  let value = {};

  if (key === "name1") {
   value.value = obj[key]; // key is "name1", obj[key] == "John"
   value.section = "left";
  } else if (key === "name2") {
   value.value = obj[key]; // key is "name2", obj[key] == "Jane"
   value.section = "right";
  }

  console.log(value);
}
```

This should be the output you're looking for.

If this is for an exercise where you're supposed to be using the Object methods, or if you won't know your property names in advance, comment on this answer, and I'll adjust it.